Texstudio convert to html
I'm using Texstudio and its convert-to-html button. This mwe works to create a pdf, but it does not work when I use the convert-to-html option.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  hello world
  \includegraphics[height=7.cm]{Gridiron_pendulum_on_stand.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I get the message
Compiling input file. Please wait...
Running this command: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode
"mwe_content".tex
Error : a process has failed
Fatal error : LaTeX errors detected.
But no additional information is included in a log or message. The mwe will create an html if I comment out the call to \includegraphics. I get the same responses if also comment out the calls to the figure environment. I'm using Miktex with Texstudio.

Welcome! You can't use a png with latex (as opposed to pdflatex). Try removing the .png extension, but if graphicx can't autoconvert the image, you'd need to convert it manually.

there must have been an error in teh latex log sayonh png was an unknown extension (texstudio isn't really involved here other than that it is calling latex for you)

You could try to edit what the "convert-to-html" button does, or perhaps create a new build option, to call make4ht on the file which will be able to process png images.

The issue seems to be that a bounding box cannot be found in the png image. (By the way the html processor uses a png format to store its images.) So i tried a eps image and it worked without error but the image did not appear.  I suspect it's a framing issue with the eps image.  I want to convert a document with 99 images.  It will take forever unless this problem can be solved.  Everything works properly with all the images properly processed and no bounding box issues in the pdf format, What is missing here?

i solved the problem by using htlatex this mwe works \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 hello world 3 and how do you make a figure.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[natwidth=100,natheight=200]{Gridiron_pendulum_on_stand.png}
\includegraphics[height=5.cm]{FIG101.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document} the texstudio convert button doesnt.

See the above comment. This is a mwe that works for htlat but it does not work for the texstudio convert button.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

  hello world 3 and how do you make a figure. 

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[natwidth=100,natheight=200]{Gridiron_pendulum_on_stand.png}
\includegraphics[height=5.cm]{FIG101.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

